# Does the Kochen–Specker theorem allow to show experimentally the trouble with hidden variable theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality

[Kochen–Specker theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochen%E2%80%93Specker_theorem) is one of the 'no-go' theorems for hidden variables theories. Is it possible using Kochen–Specker theorem to show experimentally that hidden variables theories reproducing QM numerically are indeed in trouble (at least), like it is possible using Bell theorem? If yes, then how?

Comment: The short answer is that experiments have been performed to test if reality matches the Kochen Specker theorem, e.g. - https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1836

Comment: Note that Kochen-Specher theorem does not disprove hidden variables, it disproves *non-contextual* hidden variables theories.

Comment: @Mauricio If an experiment demonstrates non-contextuality where it should not be according to Kochen–Specker this is a trouble for all hidden variables.

Comment: @kludg Bell's theorem has not stopped people from modelling nonlocal hidden variables, KS theorem will not stop people from modelling contextual hidden variables.

Comment: @Mauricio: I am not against, maybe they''ll discover something useful. I just want to clarify things to myself.

Comment: A bit of an elaborate what exactly KS is saying is in this answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/750131/304394). I admit that I have to think hard about contextual/non-contextual every time I get back to these matters.

Comment: The motivation of my question is: without experiment, contextuality is just a peculiar feature of hidden variables, of little interest since hidden variables are not mainstream. Experiment confronts contextuality with reality, and it makes difference.