# What interpretations are ruled out by the Kochen–Specker theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality, bohmian-mechanics

What interpretations are ruled out by this theorem (such as superdeterminism, Bohmian mechanics, or ensemble interpretations) and does it function similarly to Bell's theorem as a 'no-go' theorem?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/750068/how-are-gleasons-and-kochen-speckers-theorems-related/750131#750131).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kochen-Specker theorem proves that *non-contextual hidden variable theories* (those where hidden variables are associated with the system only, not with the measurement setup) are not compatible with quantum theory.

Interpretations are not all physical theories, thus one should not expect/require them to be falsifiable. But even those that are also a hidden variable theory, such as the Bohm theory, are not necessarily non-contextual, so the theorem does not apply.

In Bohm's theory, the measurement setup is made of material particles too, and has its own "hidden variables". Thus the key assumption of the theorem is not satisfied, and the theorem result does not apply. Similarly for other possible theories from the class of contextual hidden variable theories (e.g. the "superdeterminism" ideas).

This situation, where some assumption in the no-go theorem is not necessarily satisfied in the hidden variable theory, is quite a typical deficiency of the various past proclamations of some theorem defeating all hidden variable theories. There are always assumptions in such theorems; if you prove a lot, it's because you assume a lot, and such big assumptions are often not obvious to be necessary (to get a theory that agrees with experiments).